# Scala: Good way to extending "static" trait

Tags: scala

I have a trait and some classes extending it. The problem is that all method in the trait should be implemented statically, so I put them in the corresponding companion objects.
I wrote something like:

A.scala

```
trait A
```

C1.scala

```
class C1 extends A {
  override def F = C1.F
}
object C1 extends A {
  def F: String = ???
}
```

...

As the method `F` has to be implemented twice, I added a corresponding companion trait.

Now I have something like:

A.scala

```
trait A
```

AC.scala

```
trait AC {
 def F: String
}
```

C1.scala

```
class C1 extends A {
}
object C1 extends AC {
  def F: String = ???
}
```

C2.scala

```
class C2 extends A {
}
object C2 extends AC {
  def F: String = ???
}
```

...

I feel a little strange because there is nothing but an empty trait `A` in A.scala. I wonder if there is any better way to organize the codes.

Comment: You do not need `A` however there is no way to force something to have a companion object and thus no way to force it to extend some trait. - However, IMHO, everytime you need something like this, you can use a [**Typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) instead.

Comment: @jwvh I use AC because if I write `class C1 extends A` and `object C1 extends A` I will have to write the implementation of  method `F` twice.

Comment: Does the empty trait `A` mark anything? If not, you can simply delete it without any loss.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the Typeclass suggestion. I've read it briefly but I'm not sure whether it helps. The background of my question is that trait `A` defined the set of available input of a not-mentioned function. I am writing the instances of `A` like `C1`, but  I don't want to extends it twice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but I don't want to extends it twice". All concrete entities in your example extend exactly one trait. If those entities need to extend something - fine. If not - also fine, remove the super-trait. I see no problem with your code as it already is.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I updated the question, the key problem is how to organize the code when all methods in the trait are static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you should first consider whether you really want any methods in the trait `A`, or whether you could move it into a typeclass (you have a companion object already anyway). The result will look like ordinary method invocation, but all such invocations will, per definition, go through the typeclass instance.

---

That being said, if you prefer "extending"...

If there are multiple methods in trait `A`, and they all should be implemented in the companion object, you could use the following classic OOP-ish pattern from Scala collections:

```
trait A[C <: A[C]] {
  self: C =>
  def companion: ACompanion[C]           // one abstract `def`
  def f(): String = companion.f()        // implemented once
}

trait ACompanion[C <: A[C]] {
  def f(): String
}

class C1 extends A[C1] {
  val companion = C1                     // one line per class `C_N`
}

object C1 extends ACompanion[C1] {
  def f() = "that's a C1"                // all actual implementation in companion
}

println(new C1().f())
```

The idea is that in the trait `A`, the methods that rely on the companion (like `f`), are delegated to the `companion` (thus, they are defined once as `companion.f()`).

In the implementing classes, you only have to specify what the `companion` is (one line per subclass).

This can reduce amount of boilerplate if there are multiple classes like `C1` ... `C_N`, and more methods like `f`.